# Views and node references

Tags: nodes, views

I have 3 content types. Town, Hotel and Price. Hotel has a node-reference to Town, Price has a node reference to Hotel.

I'm trying to create a block view to use one the Town node page displaying a list of Hotel nodes in that town, together with the lowest Price (field_price of the Price node).

Is something like that achievable with views? I did manage to get a list of all hotels in a town by using a contextual filter, but I can't seem to get the additional step of getting the prices in the view.

A custom module would obviously be an option, but if it's possible with views, I would prefer that solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a relationship from Hotel to Price. You have to go the other way.

Create a block view of Price. Configure a Relationship on the node reference to Hotel (`field_hotel`), and make it required. Add `Content:field_price` (not using relationship) and `Content:Title` (using the relationship) to your display, Add a sort on `field_price` (Ascending).

To limit the display to the Town, create a Contextual filter on `field_town`, have it use the relationship, and set it to *Provide default value:Content ID from URL*.

Configure your block to display on the Town content type, and you are done.